# Prevent Select sql from select the same data from DB PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I Have some question about the Seq in PHP.
I create 1 tabel to maintain the sequence table,
ex. table is sequence and the field is seq(start from 1)
The sequence should be unique value.

The problem is.
there is 2 process which is run parallel that will use it.
and I got the error message that say duplicate value.

The question.
How to lock the table from another select query?

this is my code

```
//select seq
$sqlSeq = "select seq from sequence for update";
$resultSeq = pg_query($sqlSeq);
$rowSeq = pg_fetch_assoc($resultSeq);
$seqCif = $rowSeq['seq'];

//INSERT
$sqlInsert1 ="insert into TEST (customer_id) values( '".$seqCif."')";

//UPDATE 
 $sqlInsert1 .= "update sequence set seq=seq+1;" ;
```

Can you help me for this case?
Many Thanks befor..

Comment: Why don't you use sequences that postgresql has built in? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: Becarfull your code contains SQL Injection, take a look here for more information : https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: hi @FelippeDuarte, If I use Auto increment, if the insert is failed, the sequence is still increase, and that the problem. I can't skip the number.

Comment: @Inazo yes, I know, but this tools is for internal purpose. So I think is safe...

Comment: Use transactions then

Comment: @LodeweykAndri you make a mistake if you think this... Internal application can be exploited too

Comment: Don't bother about skipped numbers. They mean nothing.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte what do you mean about transaction?

Comment: @Inazo yes, of course, I will change it letter. but I need to resolve this issue first.

Comment: @jarlh the sequence will be on audit check. So I need to think about the solution

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to make the operation atomic and to guarantee an incremental `id` without gaps is to turn the statement to an `insert ... select ...` query:

```
insert into test(customer_id)
select coalesce(max(customer_id), 0) + 1 from test
```

Comment: I can't use that method, because I create ETL tools, and the table (test) is used by existing core program, and the sequence I that I created is only from my tools.

ex.
the core is C00001
my tools is M00001

Comment: @LodeweykAndri: we can extract the numeric part, increment it and reformat it: `insert into test(customer_id) select 'C' || lpad((coalesce(max(substring(customer_id, 2)::int), 0) + 1)::text, 5, '0') from test`